# how to add different column with one code into one column?

Tags: oracle

```
id    text 
 1     hi
 1     how are u
 1     fine ?
 2     rad
 2     qey
 3
```

I am searching for a query where it can let me insert id = 1 to another table in one column

```
  id   test
  1     hi how are you fine ?
  2     rad qey
```

with the listagg function , i will have such result : hi how are you fine ? .. can i have it such
hi
how are u
fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query can be used to achieve your result:

```
WITH tab(id,text) AS (
 SELECT 1, 'hi' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 'how are u' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 'fine ?' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'rad' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'qey' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, NULL FROM dual)
-----
--End of data
-----
SELECT ID, 
       listagg(text, ' ') within GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS text
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY ID;
```

Output

```
ID  TEXT
1   hi how are u fine ?
2   rad qey
3
```

But there is one problem, although order by rownum is used but you cannot guaranty the order of text, its better to have one more column in your table that can define the order of the text as below

```
id    text         order_text 
 1     hi          1
 1     how are u   2
 1     fine ?      3
 2     rad         1
 2     qey         2
 3                 1
```

and the use the query as

```
SELECT ID, 
       listagg(text, ' ') within GROUP (ORDER BY order_text) AS text
  FROM tab
  GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: well I have thousand of columns , is there a way the order_text can be set automaticly ? and is there a way where the test be with eneters ? check the edit @san

Answer (score -1):

You can try the LISTAGG function.
For more information, [see here.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)